# Uncought Error injector::modulerr

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, dependencies, config

How can i get this Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
by calling 
`angular.module('App', []).config(function () { });` ?

The whole project worked correctly without any calls to .config(), but
i recently tried to add ng-route and got into this error even after removing any dependencies the bare config() throws the exception.

Comment: Could you paste original `.config([with_dependency_inj_module],....)` instead of this line `config([], function () { });` ?? May be this will give clear idea what exactly you use there

Comment: And did you used `angular.module('App', [])` anywhere before this config file `angular.module('App', []).config`?

Comment: I didnt use angular.module before
`angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate', 'angular.filter', 'ui.bootstrap', 'nvd3', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$rootProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     when('/1', {
         //..
     }).
     when('/2', {
         //...
     }).
     otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
     });
}]);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
 angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate', 'angular.filter', 'ui.bootstrap', 'nvd3', 'ngRoute']) 
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) 
        { 
            $routeProvider. 
            when('/1', { //.. }). 
            when('/2', { //... }). 
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
        }
        ]);
```

//You wrongly spelled `routeProvider` while injecting thats why you getting this error!

Comment: can you explain why the empty call (angular.module(..).config()) threw the same error ?

Comment: There was spelling mistake with your DI module. You used name `$rootProvider` instead of `'$routeProvider'` thats why it was showing error ` $injector:modulerr ` i.e. problem with module while injecting :) And re to empty call, i didn't get you

Comment: Im referring to my first question, why did the call to .config() without any dependencies throw an error

Comment: Did you use that like this one --- > `.config(function ($routeProvider) 
        { 
            $routeProvider. 
            when('/1', { //.. }). 
            when('/2', { //... }). 
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
        });  `?